# Spring data JPA and Geometry type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application that will run on both MySql and MS SQL.

I have a field that is "geometry" type for spatial.

By using:

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry")
 private Point geometry;
```

(point is org.springframework.data.geo.Point)

Hibernate creates the field properly (hbm2ddl).

But inserting any point does not work.
I get : Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

I use spring-boot-jpa-starter.. and not direct hibernate.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Have you specified  a `Hibernate Spatial dialect`. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial

Comment: Yes i have. Still not working

Comment: Can you share a `Spring Data Repository` class and a `Spring Boot` configuration properties/yml

Comment: Probably your point should be from following package `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;`
See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-types

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hello I have successfully mapped a point in JPA. Here's what I did:

1. I have this on Maven:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
       <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
       <version>1.13</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I have this on my entity:

   ```
   @Column(name = "locationpoint", columnDefinition = "POINT") 
   private Point locationpoint;
   ```
3. I have this on my application.properties:

   ```
   # needed for Location domain class
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect
   ```
4. I can get the value using this:

   ```
   locationRepository.findOne((long) 1).getLocationpoint().getX();
   locationRepository.findOne((long) 1).getLocationpoint().getY();
   ```

I based my solution from here Matti Tahvonen's example:

https://github.com/mstahv/spring-boot-spatial-example

Hope this helps.

Comment: I face those issues and gathered thereafter my react springboot mini dem in https://github.com/hbadri1/React_Springboot_Mapbox/blob/master/README.md